# Zend Mail is declared as Ratware

Tags: zend-mail

I'm using Zend_mail with SMTP in a wrapper class like this:

```
//$_config has all required and valid attributes to send a mail successfully.
$tmpconfig = Array('auth' => 'login',
                    'username' => $this->_config->MAIL_LOGIN,
                    'password' => $this->_config->MAIL_PASSWORT);

$this->_transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($this->_config->MAIL_SMTP,$tmpconfig);
$this->_mail = new Zend_Mail();
$this->_mail->setFrom($this->_config->MAIL_ADDRESS, $this->_config->MAIL_SENDER_NAME);
...

//$_data has already all required and valid fields and values...

$this->_mail->setBodyText($this->_data['maildata']['BodyText'],'UTF-8','UTF-8');
$this->_mail->setSubject($this->_data['maildata']['Subject']);
$this->_mail->addTo($this->_data['maildata']['RecipientEmail'], $this->_data['maildata']['RecipientName']);

$this->_mail->send($this->_transport);
```

Scenario 1: I'm sending the Mail with a test account to a proprietary server to a test mailaddress from my testsystem. This mail will be received.

Scenario 2: I'm sending the Mail with another test account to another proprietary server to the same mailaddress, with two test systems. This mail is rejected as ratware. I've already talked to the server administrator, he said that the mail generation is incorrect. There is no valid EHLO greeting: "remote host used our name in HELO/EHLO greeting."

I don't really know if its a problem within the zend_mail class or the test systems.

1st Testsystem: PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14, Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

2nd Testsystem: PHP Version 5.3.1, Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) (Apache on Mac OS X)

Comment: You lost me when you began explaining Scenario 2.  Who's sending what and where?  What is ratware?  Can you post the exact error message you're getting?  Also, what version of Zend Framework are you using?  I'm using version 1.11.10 and Zend_Mail is working fine sending with my SMTP server which is Google Apps' mail system.

Comment: The Mailserver which recieves the Emails from the Zend_Mail class via SMTP checks the Hostname in the EHLO/HELO-Greeting AND checks the hostname of the source host. Of course they don't match! Zend_mail puts the hostname of the SMTP-Server into the EHLO/HELO-Greeting. So the mailserver gets confused, because it receives an Email from a host that predends to has it's name, but in fact has another name. In this case you can understand "Ratware" as refused mails.

Answer (score 0):

I think your 2nd mail server is configured too strictly, or perhaps it's a problem with how you're configuring `Zend_Mail`.  `Zend_Mail` works great for me, and I'm using it to send emails to multiple SMTP servers, including the ones at Gmail and also at a popular shared web hosting service.

If you're sending on port 25, I believe many mail servers are more likely to treat your message as Spam.  Does your 2nd mail server support sending with alternate ports?  Typical alternatives are 465 or 587.  Also, have you tried sending [via SSL or TLS](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.mail.smtp-secure.html)?  These might also help convince that server that your messages are legitimate.

Comment: Perhaps I've formulated my questrion too complicated, but your answer describes only the problem. And as I tried to point out, there is NO way to configue the server more tolerant. So the question has to be: How to configure Zend_Mail suitable for this case?

Comment: It only supports port 25?  And there are no alternate ports you can try?  And no SSL or TLS?  In my definition that would _not_ represent a typical robust, security-conscious mail server.

Comment: I realize you may have read my answer before I added the part about port numbers.  Sorry about that.  Anyway, if you can send on any alternate ports and/or use a secure SMTP protocol, I think that would solve the problem.